# Python - Getting Items From List Using Day Name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a program that gets the date, works out what lessons i have.

```
import datetime

def getdate():

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(now.strftime("%A"))

day=getdate()

##LESSON LIST###
################
Lessons = [
Monday=['English','Geography','German','P.E.','Science-C']
Tuesday=['Art','Science-B','Maths','ICT','French']
Wednesday=['History','English','Drama','Science-B','Maths']
Thursday=['P.E.','D&T','HTT','Geography','R.E.']
Friday=['German','D&T','Maths','English','Music']
]
################
#END LESSON LIST

Today = Lessons[day]
print("1) Book Check")
print("2) Timetable List")
x = input()
if x = 1:
    #List lessons for this day one by one with a book input eg.
    print("book for lesson1")
    l1 = bool(input("True/False"))
    print("book for lesson2")
    l2 = bool(input("True/False"))
    #but it should say the lesson name, and save the state of book boolean

elif x = 2:
    #list lessons for this day
    print(Today) # just an example.
```

Currently, I get a syntax error that I cannot fix, I can't find where I have gone wrong. I would like to use a dictionary to complete my code but I am unsure how to.

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Use a dictionary instead of a list? and also what is your question?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries <- read this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have a major error in how you are trying to form a dict. It should be this:

```
Lessons = {
'Monday':['English','Geography','German','P.E.','Science-C'],
'Tuesday':['Art','Science-B','Maths','ICT','French'],
'Wednesday':['History','English','Drama','Science-B','Maths'],
'Thursday':['P.E.','D&T','HTT','Geography','R.E.'],
'Friday':['German','D&T','Maths','English','Music']
}
```

This is a dictionary called Lessons that has Strings as keys (the days of the weeks) and Lists as values (The lists of lessons). To access a list of lessons you would do it like so:

```
Lessons['Monday']
```

Note that this returns a list, if you want it formatted differently, then you can do something like this:

```
", ".join(Lessons['Monday'])
```

This will give you a comma-separated list of lessons.

I am unsure what exactly you are trying to do with books, but if you want to be more specific I will update my answer. However, I can say that if you will be running this program each day, then you will need to store information about the books in a file to maintain their state, otherwise it will be lost when the program ends.

Also, variables should be lower-cased (lessons instead of Lessons), but I kept it how you had it to be consistent.

Comment: Notice the colons, not equals sign, in the dictionary. To separate keys and values it's a colon like 'Monday': List, not 'Monday'=List